# How to to connect two ionic app together?

Tags: ionic-framework

could you please share your Idea or technique to connect to or more apps together without backend coding or database? using for example `direct messaging` or `sending text, data(realtime)to each other`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custome URL Schema. (search on the net for more detail)
Here is one such [plugin(deeplink)](http://blog.ionic.io/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/) which explores custom URL Schema.

This way one Application can start another Application and pass extra parameters.

Comment: thanks, I accept it, it was useful, but may be its my bad question I want to make relation in 2 different devices.

Comment: Go for Peer-to-peer solution. like peerjs. but at list you need one server for searching/scanning peers.   see how skype works. some libraries you can use are peerjs(for audio,call).